# Resize root filesystem in gparted

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, gparted

I'm trying to reisize my root filesystem in gparted, but when I try to drag the partition it won't do anything. if I change the number in the size field, it jumps back to where it was before. I need to resize it in order to make space for dual-booting Windows 10. This is my internal hard drive, `/dev/sda`:

[partition map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRHCT.png)

Green is `/dev/sda1`, mounted at `/boot/efi`,
Blue is `/dev/sda2`, mounted at `/`,
Red is `/dev/sda3`, a linux swap, and
Grey is free space, there's only 1.02 MiB, obviously not enough for Windows 10, or really anything.

I select `/dev/sda2` and click Partition > Resize/Move. I can't drag the partition or change the size number. This is what it looks like.

[resize/move menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqFcT.png)

I sincerely hope that someone will help. thanks

## Update:

I found what might be a clue. There is a little icon of a key beside the  name in the partition list. does that mean the partition is "locked" at its size? If so, how can I "unlock" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to **unmount** the partitions.

Refer to the following question for more information:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/277399/how-to-unlock-partition-in-gparted

> If partitions are showed with a lock in gparted, then they are mounted. Usually gparted is able to unmount them, but sometimes this isn't possible, so you have to manually unmount them...

Comment: I cannot unmount `/dev/sda2` because it is in use. I'll have to download gparted live, thanks for your help.`